# Split a txt file into two files using first column value in Python

Tags: python, file-io

I would like to split a INPUT.txt file into two .txt files(Header & Data) by the value of the first column. Data before "H1000" will save in a header.txt file and after/equal to "H1000" will save in data.txt file.

**INPUT.txt**

```
H0002   Version 78                                                                                                                      
H0003   Date_generated  5-Aug-81                                                                                                                        
H0004   Reporting_period_end_date   09-Jun-81                                                                                                                       
H1000   State   WAAAA                                                                                                                       
H1002   Teno/Combno Z70/4000                                                                                                                        
H1003   Tener   Magn Reso NL    
H1004   LLD                                                                                     
D   AC056SCO1   NRM 11  12  6483516 25.98   0.4 1.35    0.25    0.51    0.01    0.06    0.1 56.23   2.29
```

With the output files being:

**header.txt**

```
H0002   Version 78                                                                                                                      
H0003   Date_generated  5-Aug-81                                                                                                                        
H0004   Reporting_period_end_date   09-Jun-81
```

**data.txt**

```
H1000   State   WAAAA                                                                                                                       
H1002   Teno/Combno Z70/4000                                                                                                                        
H1003   Tener   Magn Reso NL    
H1004   LLD                                                                                     
D   AC056SCO1   NRM 11  12  6483516 25.98   0.4 1.35    0.25    0.51    0.01    0.06    0.1 56.23   2.29
```

Couple of problem that I am facing:

1. "H1000" position is dynamic in different txt files. If you see another input file see "H1000" position is different(Check **Input File2**). So my python code is first finding the position of H1000.
2. I am using the position of H1000 for separating Header & Data file. Logic is not working correctly in separating the files.

**My python code:**

```
if path_txt.is_file():
        txt_files = [Path(path_txt)] 
    else:
        txt_files = list(Path(path_txt).glob("*.txt"))
    
    for fn in txt_files:
       with open(fn) as fd_read:
            for line in fd_read:
               h_value = line.split(maxsplit=1)[0]
               value = int(h_value[1:]) #Finding the position of H1000
                   
            splitLen = 5  # Position of H1000
            HeaderBase = 'Header.txt'  # Header.txt
            DataBase = 'Data.txt'  # Data.txt

            with open(fn, 'r') as fp:
                input_list = fp.readlines()
                # to skip empties: input_list = [l for l in fp if l.strip()]

            for i in range(0, len(input_list), splitLen):
                with open(HeaderBase, 'w') as fp:
                    fp.write(''.join(input_list[0:(i-1)])) #Header.txt
                with open(DataBase, 'w') as fp:
                    fp.write(''.join(input_list[i:]))   #Data.txt
```

None of my logic is working. Any help as I have stuck how to work this logic.

**InputFile2**

```
H0002   Version 9                                                                                                                       
H0003   Date_generated  5-Aug-81                                                                                                                        
H0004   Reporting_period_end_date   09-Jun-99                                                                                                                       
H0005   State   WAAAAA                                                                                                                      
H1000   Tene_no/Combined_rept_no    E79/38975                                                                                                                       
H1001   Tene_holder Magne Resources NL  
D   abc3SCO1    NORM    26  27  9483531 4.15    0.05    0.65    0.02    0.15    0   0.04    0.09    87.51   0.29
```

Python code and txt file attached [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1jVCmNBovGrcNonpkhrUxsO7hRUz5_gN0?usp=sharing)

Comment: You code has numerous issues, but before fixing them,  I have a question: When a directory is passed, are all headers from all .txt files go to the same `header.txt`? Same for `data.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code suffers from numerous issues:

1. You don't actually find the position of `H1000`. I don't see it written in the code.
2. You set the split to be `5`, disregarding the position of `H1000`.
3. I don't understand your `range()` function. You're hopping from start to end in 5 line jumps?
4. For every jump `i`, you write everything from the start of the document till `i` to `header.txt` and the rest to `data.txt`. That means you're writing the entire document multiple times.
5. You change `path_txt` to a `Path` object, but then use it regularly like a string.

I couldn't figure out what to do in case a directory is passed, as having all headers in same file and all data in same file is not what you wish I believe.

Fixed code for a single file:

```
SPLIT_TOKEN = "H1000"

def split_file(path, header_path="header.txt", data_path="data.txt"):
    """Split a file to a header and data file upon encountering a token."""
    header = []
    data = []
    with open(path, "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.startswith(SPLIT_TOKEN):
                break
            header.append(line)
        
        data.append(line)  # Add the line with the token
        data.extend(f)

    with open(header_path, "w") as f:
        f.writelines(header)
    with open(data_path, "w") as f:
        f.writelines(data)
```